# Android Share sound + Text

Tags: android, audio

I have a method that shares a sound using other apps (Whatsapp, gmail, et..) working fine from the first, but now I see some apps can share a Text + Image in whatsapp like this:
[image: Whatsapp Image share]
It's possible that I can make some like these but sharing a sound (mp3 or wav file), If not possible, I can share a text and just next the sound in individual intents?